# Will hanging stuff on shower frame weaken it?

Tags: shower

I have a 2-sided shower cubicle with a sliding door; the frame is fixed to a tiled wall. My tenants hang wet suits on the frame; will it weaken the frame from the wall over time?

Comment: A picture of the door fame, focusing on how the top crossbar is attached to and supported by the walls or side rails, would help answer this question.  If it is screwed to the wall you'll want to know if the screws attach to studs or just to wall plugs.  You may need to remove them to be sure.    A way to circumvent the question:  A damp bathroom is not the best place to dry wet suits.  You could offer them some other place, like a garage, they might appreciate it.

Comment: Not enough information provided.  Assuming it is not made from thin plastic and is sitting on the floor, wet suits should not weaken it(as long as the people are out of them).

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, it's unlikely to weaken the *frame*.

It is, however, possible that it will pull the frame from the wall if it's not mounted well. You would need to do some additional investigation of how it's mounted to assess that possibility.

- If the frame is mounted directly into studs, it's unlikely that some weight, bearing straight down on top of the frame will cause any damage at all.

  - The very short-term lateral motion of the wet suit hitting the side of the wall as someone flops it over the top is also *very* unlikely to cause any issue.
- If the frame is mounted into anchors into drywall/backer board, then the chances of it pulling out increase.

  - How much it increases by will be determined by the type of anchors used and the accuracy of the anchor installation. (A too-large hole could lead to a loose fit, allowing the anchors to wobble and, eventually, pull out.)

You could remove the frame from the wall to check if you desire. If you see screws going directly into the wall through holes just the size of the screw itself, there is a high probability they went directly into a stud. (There's always the possibility that someone used a regular screw into drywall without an anchor, but your shower walls would be pretty wobbly by now if that happened.) If you see some sort of plastic bit around where the screws went in, they definitely missed a stud so anchors of some sort were used.

Another option would be to use a stud finder on the wall above where the shower walls end. If it detects a stud above the wall, you should be fine.

I'm not aware of any way of determining what kind of anchor was used without actually pulling it from the wall to check. If you pull the anchor from the wall, you'll cause damage that *will* have to be repaired before reinstalling the shower walls. This will also include repairing the tiles and that's probably more work than it's worth.

#### TL;DR:

Unless the shower walls are already wobbly, it's rather unlikely that hanging things *over* the shower walls will cause any issue, even heavy items like wet suits.

Body checking a fellow surfer *into* the shower wall is likely to cause damage, no matter how well mounted it is.

Comment: Getting ready for hockey season?

Comment: surfer === hockey player.